# if I open my spring app in eclipse and netbeans, will they both create their own files?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, maven

If I open my application in both eclipse and netbeans (having created the file layout using maven), will both eclipse and netbeans create their own project file?

I know netbeans has an option of opening an existing project, but not sure if it will add files to my project?

Comment: mrblah, you are of course free to downvote my answer - and I know **you** did - but you should seriously start to reconsider your "help vampire" attitude. Here, your question is about a trivial thing but you didn't even try to find the answer yourself. No, instead, you're asking people to do it for you. Actually, I don't think you understood my advice in this previous answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053416/can-spring-support-multi-applications-sharing-membership/2053533#2053533. Or maybe you should reread that paper.

Comment: how do you know?  why think the worst of someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as NetBeans is concerned, it has seamless interoperability with Maven, and it recognises Maven projects out of the box.

In our environment, few developers are biased towards Eclipse. So, we let them stick with Eclipse. Our projects are all Maven based, and there is no problem in opening those in Eclipse or NetBeans.

Even if you find that they created some files, don't check-in those files in your repo.

Comment: yeah I guess you can just create excludes in SVN/GIT and be done with it!  what IDE do you use if not eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

> If I open my application in both eclipse and netbeans (having created the file layout using maven), will both eclipse and netbeans create their own project file?

They will do what they require to do. Why bother anyway?

> I know netbeans has an option of opening an existing project, but not sure if it will add files to my project?

No, it won't but... **Why the hell don't you just try?** I seriously don't get it.